# driver uninstall windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, device-manager

What I found in my Windows 7 PC that there is no Intel wireless driver package showing in program and features under control panel. I guess its using driver built in windows 7.

So how can I completely uninstall existing built in windows driver and install Intel specific driver and forced windows to use always Intel specific? Is this mandatory/required to reboot the computer after uninstalling drivers whether from add/remove programs or different method and also is reboot required for installing driver as well?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I completely uninstall existing built in windows drivers?

Use the Device Manager:

> When you need to uninstall a driver completely, the best and safest
>   method is to use the device’s uninstaller program (if it has one). If
>   you added the device to your system through an installer (as is the
>   case with most graphics card and sound card drivers, for instance),
>   you can uninstall it just as you would any other program.
>
> 1. Click Start, type Uninstall Program, and press Enter.
> 2. In the Uninstall window that appears, go through the list and find your device or drivers. Double-click the entry to begin the
>      uninstallation process.
>
> **Sometimes devices won’t have an uninstaller, or the uninstaller will not appear in the list. In those instances, you can use the Device Manager to remove the driver completely.**
>
> 1. Click Start, type Device Manager, and press Enter.
> 2. Find and double-click the category of device whose driver you wish to uninstall (for example, the graphics card would be listed
>      under Display Adapters).
> 3. Right-click the device, and click Uninstall.
> 4. Windows will prompt you to confirm the device’s removal. Click OK to remove the driver.
> 5. After the uninstallation is complete, reboot your computer as soon as possible.
>
> [image]

Source [How to Uninstall Drivers in Windows](http://www.pcworld.com/article/246041/how_to_uninstall_drivers_in_windows.html)

> Is this mandatory/required to reboot the computer after uninstalling drivers whether from add/remove programs or different method and also is reboot required for installing driver as well?

A reboot is recommended. If it is mandatory then the uninstall program will ask you to reboot.

Comment: @alex part of your comment is missing ...

Comment: When I select uninstall, it prompts confirm device removal as a warning. Now the confusing part is there is option:

Delete the driver software for this device. Should that be checked or unchecked?

Apart from that I noticed that, after uninstalling using device manager and then rebooting PC, Windows automatically start downloading/installing driver for that device. 

So how can I install only Intel specific driver rather than windows to install driver automatically after reboot? How to force windows to use only Intel specific driver not using built in driver.

Comment: "Delete the driver software for this device" that's optional because you might want to use this driver again if the new on doesn't work properly.

Comment: "How to force windows to use only Intel specific driver" If you install the new driver before rebooting then Windows should use it ...

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to uninstall anything, just install the Intel driver and Window will handle the rest.